# Xubuntu 16.04 Broadcom BCM43 wireless driver does not work

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

I followed these [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20No%20Internet%20access) and installed firmware-b43-installer. The WiFi started to work, but very unreliably and sometimes very slow. I have Windows 7 as the second OS on the same laptop and WiFi there works fine.

I also followed advice from similar questions and reinstalled bcmwl-kernel-source and checked blacklist.

Today, it has stopped to work completely: I see the wireless networks but I cannot connect to them (it just showing the spinning wheel every time).

Maybe the problem is not in WiFi module itself, as now I also cannot change any proprietary driver: if I select another driver from the list for Nvidia nothing changes, or if select 'do not use this device' for Broadcom also nothing changes. The previously selected drivers are still marked as selected.

I received the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNpzy.png) message when I tried to change the driver yesterday.

My system is Xubuntu 16.04, installed a week ago.

Is it worth to try NDISWrapper in my case?

```
oz@aspire:~$ lspci -vnn -d 14e4:
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b5] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [1025:0504]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at d1830000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Memory at d1840000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Expansion ROM at 9fb00000 [disabled] [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3


02:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Broadcom Corporation BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader [14e4:16bc] (rev 10) (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader [1025:0504]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at d1800000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci


02:00.2 System peripheral [0880]: Broadcom Corporation BCM57765/57785 MS Card Reader [14e4:16be] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] BCM57765/57785 MS Card Reader [1025:0504]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 7
    Memory at d1810000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>


02:00.3 System peripheral [0880]: Broadcom Corporation BCM57765/57785 xD-Picture Card Reader [14e4:16bf] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] BCM57765/57785 xD-Picture Card Reader [1025:0504]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 7
    Memory at d1820000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>


03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43227 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4358]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43227 802.11b/g/n [105b:e040]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at d1900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

---

```
oz@aspire:~$ apt-cache search broadcom-sta-dkms
broadcom-sta-dkms - dkms source for the Broadcom STA Wireless driver
broadcom-sta-source - Source for the Broadcom STA Wireless driver
```

---

```
oz@aspire:~$  iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.


enp2s0f0  no wireless extensions.


wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Ufanet_43"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 22:4A:03:77:BD:F0   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

---

```
oz@aspire:~$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for oz: 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0f0
       version: 10
       serial: b8:70:f4:ed:5e:60
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 duplex=full firmware=sb ip=100.94.228.134 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:d1830000-d183ffff memory:d1840000-d184ffff memory:9fb00000-9fb007ff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43227 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: cc:af:78:07:16:9e
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:d1900000-d1903fff
```

---

```
oz@aspire:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

---

```
oz@aspire:~$ dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.065652] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    4.357377] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 3 (with firmware version 0x450f01)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have received the answer from user [Hadaka](https://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=1599436) and will post it here for someone who experiences the same problem.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcma
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source

sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
sudo sed -i '/ipv6/{n;s/.*/method=ignore/}' /etc/NetworkManager/*/Ufanet_43
systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

All thanks to Hadaka